# What placeholder is used for list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Is there a format placeholder for a list in Python, e.g., in the same way that "`%s`" is a format placeholder for a string, and "`%d`" is a placeholder for an integer?

I have a list:

```
result_list = [{"a": "EC2", "b": 300}, {"a": "VPC", "b": 102}, {"a": "S3", "b": 140}]
```

and want to put the contents of the list into a string. If `results_list` were itself a string I could use:

```
my_str = "input_list = %s"
print(my_str % (result_list))
```

but how would I do this given that `result_list` is a list?

Comment: What output do you expect to get?

Comment: I have edited the question. It will be more clear now

Comment: If anything, its now less clear

Comment: What does `%s` do that you don't expect?

Comment: What result do you expect/want to achieve?

Comment: Use the string format method: `my_str = "input_list = {}"` and then `print(my_str.format(results_list))`. `format` will "format" string representations of most objects.

Comment: I think you should say what you expect the output of your `print` call to be. Your code will work but the output clearly not what you expect. What is not clear is what you *do* expect.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the string format method, e.g.:

```
result_list = [{"a": "EC2", "b": 300}, {"a": "VPC", "b": 102}, {"a": "S3", "b": 140}]

my_str = "input_list: {}"
print(my_str.format(result_list))
```